# How do I make PyScripter work? Says it cant find python26.dll

Tags: python, pythonpath, pyscripter

I installed PyScript to try it out but it just wont start. It only gives me the error:
"Error126: Could not open Dll "python26.dll" followed by:
"Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit."

I think this may have something to do with the PYTHONPATH but since I'm a newbie and dont know what it is or exactly what to put in the PYTHONPATH, after some googling, I ask here.

Also, when I tried to install wxPython it was impossible becouse the PYTHONPATH could not be found.(Just a side note)

Comment: PyScript (http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscript/files/) and Pyscripter (http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) are very different applications

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Edit**: PyScripter don't need wxPython to run that.

and Looks like you have 64bit python, according to your comment.

but pyscripter site says, you need 32 bit version of python

> If you are using a 64bit version of
>   Windows note that PyScripter will only
>   work if a 32bit version of Python is
>   installed.

So, only the way is you need to [download](http://python.org/ftp/python/2.6.5/python-2.6.5.msi)/install 32 bit python and run pyscripter after that.

or

You might want to try out [ulipad](http://ulipad.googlecode.com) which works with 64 bit python and wxPython 64 bit.

Comment: How do I kow if i have unicode or not? Is it always unicode now? This confused me a bit.

Comment: Installed 64-bit version and it worked! Thanks! Now to the pyscripter problem. It refuses to start.

Comment: The questions is about PyScript, not PyScripter. In any case PyScripter is written in Delphi and doesnt need wxPython as far as I know

Comment: Well i ment pyscripter, sorry...
Fixed the title.

Comment: @Alex, looks like pyscripter not work with 64 bit python, you need to install 32 bit version of python, answer updated.

Comment: Ok, the python26.dll is located in the symstem32 folder and a subdolder to python26(C:\Python26\dist). Which directory should I add.

Updadet first post with my PATH.

Comment: @Alex, sorry, please read the answer again, pyscripter does not work with python 64 bit. you need to install 32 bit python.

Comment: Yes that has to be the problem! I wasn't realy aware of which version I had when I read that.

If I could find a version for 2.6 i would try Ulipad but i cant find it.

Answer (score 0):

Install python. should solve all your problems..

Comment: Installed python 2.6 from python.org instead but pyscripter still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I just copied python26.dll from my python folder to pyscripter folder and it worked well... dont know it that is a good way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working by (a) not changing the directory it gets installed in to something else...just left it in c:/programfiles/pyscripter ...and (B) going into the pyscripter folder and in the lib folder extracting the rpyc folder so that there is another rpyc folder inside the lib folder that isnt compressed! hope that helps